# what is query.clone(), queryset.clone() for in django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I see clone() being used extensively in django code

```
queryset.query.clone()  
queryset.clone()
```

What is it for and should I mimic the behavior in my queryset or manager methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two main reasons for `clone()`:

1. It allows chaining. When you [chain](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters) querysets together (for example, multiple `filter()` calls), you want a fresh copy of the queryset each time that you can modify.
2. It allows you to avoid stale cache results. Since querysets [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) their results when they are evaluated, if you want to make sure you hit the database again you need to clone the queryset.

If you know what you're doing you could use it, but note that it isn't a public API. In this interesting [Django developers thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-developers/clone/django-developers/qFE78ZpDP6A) the developers talk about whether or not `clone()` should be public. They decide against it, in part because:

> The biggest problem with public `.clone()` method is that the private `._clone()` doesn't do just cloning. There are some cases where cloning also changes how the QuerySet behaves.

Comment: The reason you need clone() for chaining is because?

Comment: @eugene: Although it's possible to have a chaining API that operates on a single object, Django's queryset API is [specifically designed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters) to return a new queryset each time the query is modified. The most straightforward way to do that is to copy (i.e. `clone`) the existing queryset, modify it, and then return the new object.

Answer (score 28):

As Kevin points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21389129/4794), the `clone()` method is not a documented part of the Django API. However, the [`all()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#all) is fully documented, and does what you probably wanted from `clone()`.

> #### all()
>
> Returns a copy of the current QuerySet (or QuerySet subclass). This can be useful in situations where you might want to pass in either a model manager or a QuerySet and do further filtering on the result. After calling all() on either object, you’ll definitely have a QuerySet to work with.
>
> When a QuerySet is evaluated, it typically caches its results. If the data in the database might have changed since a QuerySet was evaluated, you can get updated results for the same query by calling all() on a previously evaluated QuerySet.

Comment: And in 1.9.6, `all()` calls the internal `_clone` method: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.6/django/db/models/query.py#L783 Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804252/django-orm-objects-filter-vs-objects-all-filter-which-one-is-preferre