# Django ORM - objects.filter() vs. objects.all().filter() - which one is preferred?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-managers

Very often I see constructs like

```
MyModel.objects.all().filter(...)
```

which will return a QuerySet of the default Mananger. At first `all()` seems to be quite redundant, because

```
MyMode.objects.filter(...)
```

delivers the same result.

However, this seems to be safe for the default Manager only, because of the following two statements in the Django documentation:

Excerpt from the Chapter "Adding extra manager methods"

> A custom Manager method can return anything you want. It doesn’t have
>   to return a QuerySet.

Definition of the `all()` manager method:

> all() 
>   Returns a copy of the current QuerySet (or QuerySet subclass).
>   This can be useful in situations where you might want to pass in
>   either a model manager or a QuerySet and do further filtering on the
>   result. After calling all() on either object, you’ll definitely have a
>   QuerySet to work with.

This seems a bit like a contradiction to me. On one hand Django offers the freedom to let a manager method return whatever object type is preferred and on the other hand it requires a QuerySet for the `all()` method. I'm aware that each manager has a `get_queryset` method which is called by `all()`. But who stops me from overriding `all()` in my custom manager? Although I agree it would be bad design to do so.

- So as far as I can see, the `all()` method does not guarantee to return a QuerySet. What exactly does `MyModel.objects` return? Does this statement call `all()`? or `get_queryset()?
- Do you prefer `MyModel.objects.filter(...)` or `MyModel.objects.all().filter(...)`. And if so, why?
- Have you ever encountered wonky managers that would mess with those methods in a undesirable way?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The method `all()` on a manager just delegates to `get_queryset()`, as you can see in the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0.5/django/db/models/manager.py#L157-L164):

```
def all(self):
    return self.get_queryset()
```

So it's just a way to get the QuerySet from the Manager. This can be handy to ensure that you're dealing with a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/) and not a [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/), because `MyModel.objects` returns a Manager.

For example, if you want to iterate over all the items, you **can't** do this:

```
for item in MyModel.objects:
    # this won't work
```

Because you can't iterate over a Manager. However, `all()` returns the QuerySet, you **can** iterate over a QuerySet:

```
for item in MyModel.objects.all():
    # do someting with item
```

Generally, you should never overwrite `all()`. You can [overwrite `get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) but this method **must** return a QuerySet.

If you would use a filter method like `filter()` or `exclude()`, you would already have the QuerySet, [because these methods are proxied to the QuerySet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0.5/django/db/models/manager.py#L81-L105). So you don't have to do something like `all().filter()`.

Answer (score 6):

1. `MyModel.objects` returns the manager instance. `all()` return `get_query_set()`. I think all is there for when you need all objects.
2. I prefer `MyModel.objects.filter()` cause the other is just one more method call, and I don't need all objects if I do filter :)
3. It depends on the purpose. But if they override a base method of the manager, they return the same result format (eg. a QuerySet)

Comment: So the answer is "``objects.filter()`` is preferred, because writing ``all()`` when in fact you do _not_ want all objects is not pythonic".

Answer (score -2):

`Mymodel.objects.filter(username='abcd')` will give list of match record
`Mymodel.objects.get(pk='abcd')`  will return single record with matching on primary key value