# DJANGO importing fields to model from another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following Models and I'm try to get the vector in **Especie.zonas** to be a field in the model **Zona**.

i.e. **Especie.zonas** is a vector of Zonas (model **Zona**) and I want it to have a OneToOne relationship with the model **EspecieZona**

**Models.py**

```
class Zona(models.Model):
    codigo          = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    area            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    especies        = models.ManyToManyField("Especie", blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.codigo
        def get_especies(self):
            return self.especies.all().values_list('nome', flat=True)

    class Especie(models.Model):
        nome            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        nome_latino     = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        data_insercao   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        actualizacao    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        zonas           = models.ManyToManyField("Zona",blank=True )

        def get_zonas(self):
            return self.zonas.all().values_list('codigo', flat=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.nome

    class EspecieZona(models.Model):
        idEspecie          = models.OneToOneField("Especie")
        here_is_my_problem = models.Especie.zonas()
        idZona             = models.OneToOneField("Especie.zonas")
        fechado            = models.BooleanField()
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.idEspecie)+' em '+str(self.idZona)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of your intent. Relationships are to be established between models (so you can't OneToOne to a class' field). As I understand EspecieZona relates one Especie instance to one Zona instance, but you also would like to easily get all the Zona instances related to some Especie instance that you are accessing through EspecieZona.

It seems to me like you should drop that `here_is_my_problem` field entirely and use foreign keys to Especie and Zona in EspecieZona, instead of OneToOne. With the foreign keys you can use a ManyToMany field from Zona to Especie (or vice versa. you have to declare the MtM field in only one side of the relationship, whichever makes more sense to you) and use EspecieZona as a 'through' field for that relationship (probably with a unique_together constraint for Especie and Zona). That way you can establish a relationship like this:

*"Each species can be on multiple zones, and each zone can have multiple species* (described by the MtM relationship). *Additionally, for each zone and species found in them, each species might or not have been recorded(?) in that zone* (described in the 'through' model, EspecieZona, thou not sure I understand the meaning of `fechado` here. In any case, a 'through' model lets you describe whatever details about the relationship between two models)*"*.

Then, in order to retrieve Especies.zonas from an instance of EspecieZona you can do `someSpecificEspecieZona.especie.zonas.all()` (assuming `zonas`
 is declared as a MtM field in Especie), which would get you all the zones that are related to that species (as I understand your models)

I suggest reading through the documentation of relationship fields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related so you get the details about how it all works, like how to use a  ManyToManyField.through, and perhaps about reverse relationships if you need them.

(also, maybe that was just a mistake when copypasting your code here, but the indentation looks wrong. Different models should be at the same level of indentation there)

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer, it was both clear and useful. Apologies for perhaps not putting the question in the best of ways. Im very new to Django and sometimes I lack the vocabulary. Still, you managed to fully understand my problem!

Would you specify what you mean by "someSpecificEspecieZona.especie.zonas.all()" and how the method "someSpecificEspecieZona" would look like? i believe you are suggesting I put that inside the EspecieZona model.which django class should i attach to that? models.someSpecificEspecieZona.especie.zonas.all()?thank you again for your time & patience!

Comment: Ah, `someSpecificEspecieZona` was meant to just be a random name for an instance of the model EspecieZona. For example this line might've come before that: `someSpecificEspecieZona = EspecieZona.objects.get(id=1)`, so it was a use of the models rather than a method inside them.

With `.especie` you get the associated Especie instance, then with `.zonas` you get the Zona instances associated with that Especie instance. And `.all()` is to return a QuerySet rather than a Manager, but since I'm fairly new to Django that's a bit hard to explain for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22806277/4192226