# Django objects.filter vs objects.all

Tags: python, django, model

I have a question regarding the filter() and all() methods of django objects. It is not a question which one of the two is preferred, I just noticed an odd (to me) behavior.
Because, as it is laid out in

[Django ORM - objects.filter() vs. objects.all().filter() - which one is preferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804252/django-orm-objects-filter-vs-objects-all-filter-which-one-is-preferre)

in Django src, both ways should return the same (they both reference the chain() method):

See:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/0963f184abd96800b76b19a6a181e1b544c7fafe/django/db/models/query.py#L928

And:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/0963f184abd96800b76b19a6a181e1b544c7fafe/django/db/models/query.py#L951

So the filter() and all() method should return the same objects.
But I recently discovered the following behavior:

```
MyModel.objects.all()[0].update(name="Test")

# --> $: AttributeError: type object 'MyModel' has no attribute 'update'

# And to check if it indeed has no update method:

MyModel.objects.all[0].__dir__() # --> no update() method in returned dictionary but a save method
```

So while above code raises Error, line below would work:

```
MyModel.objects.all()[0].name = "Test"
MyModel.objects.all()[0].save()
```

However, if the same object is retrieved by the filter() method, it has the update() method.

Why do I get the same object both times but with seemingly different methods added to it?

Comment: How exactly are you using `filter()`? Are you indexing into its results as well? The return value of `filter()` or `all()` is a queryset and is expected to have an `update()` method, the return value of `all()[0]` is a model instance and is (probably) not expected to have one - if it does it's because the model class does.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the example for the filter() method. I just call `test_obj = MyModel.objects.filter(name="Test")` and then `test_obj.update(name="Test2")`

Comment: As Peter already said .update() is method on QuerySet  and it works same for both

Comment: now I see the difference. Sorry, it is a bit late here. So the objects.all() is the same as filter() but if I only return the first object by filter, I also get the update() method for this object. Whereas if I do it with `objects.all()[0]` I lose the update() method because now I am operating the model instance itself.

Comment: You didn't return first object by filter, you returned QuerySet which can contain x objects depending on your filter condition. To get to model instance you still need to index it out [0]

Comment: @iklinac, yeah, that's what I meant. I get a queryset with one object and the update()  method. And I lose the update()  method by indexing it out

Answer (score 0):

the `update()` function is only on the Manager object. Looking at your comments, you are effectively called `MyModel.objects.filter(name="Test").update(name="test2")` which is a valid queryset function. If you used `MyModel.objects.get(name="Test")` which would be the same as the `all()` version.

In your `all()` example, you are working on the model, which lacks an `update()` function.