# NoReverseMatch error when filtering from Django ListView ('is not a valid view function or pattern name')

Tags: python, django, listview, filter

I'm trying to filter the objects from a Django ListView to render them in a template, but I'm getting a 'NoReverseMatch at' error ('Reverse for 'advanced' not found. 'advanced' is not a valid view function or pattern name'). Here are my Model, View, URL, and href:

```
**Model**
class Course(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    # establishes canonical url for the Course model
        return reverse('course_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


**View**
class AdvancedListView(ListView):
    model = Course
    context_object_name = 'course_list'
    template_name = 'courses/advanced.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Course.objects.filter(
            level__icontains='Advanced')


**URL**
from django.urls import path
from .views import CourseListView, CourseDetailView, SearchResultsListView, AdvancedListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', CourseListView.as_view(), name='course_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', CourseDetailView.as_view(), name='course_detail'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsListView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('courses/', AdvancedListView.as_view(), name='advanced'),
]


**Link**
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'advanced' %}">Advanced</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
    Course.objects.all().filter(level='Advanced')
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Works perfectly now. Thanks very much for taking the time. It's much appreciated!

Comment: It's not necessary to call `all` if you're using a filter afterwards (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804252/django-orm-objects-filter-vs-objects-all-filter-which-one-is-preferre). It would be enough with `Course.objects.filter(level='Advanced')`. Also this doesn't solve the error that you are specifying, could you modify the description to match it? The error you posted is related to a urlpattern not being in your conf and this is dealing with the queryset of the view.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).